# Deserialization of JSON to enum from RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson2

Trying to consume GitHub API REST call for a user's list of emails with the following 2 classes:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * {@link GitHubEmail} class represents a description of an email address (and additional info about
 * that email address) as GitHub API stores it.
 */
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GitHubEmail {

  /**
   * Email address.
   */
  private String email;

  /**
   * Primary flag; denotes if the email address is primary one user uses. This is the one to email
   * to with the most confidence.
   */
  private boolean primary;

  /**
   * Flag that denotes if the email address has been verified by the user process.
   */
  private boolean verified;

  /**
   * If the email address is visible to the public, private, or no info (i.e., null)
   */
  private GitHubEmailVisibility visiblity;

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  public boolean isPrimary() {
    return primary;
  }

  public void setPrimary(boolean primary) {
    this.primary = primary;
  }

  public boolean isVerified() {
    return verified;
  }

  public void setVerified(boolean verified) {
    this.verified = verified;
  }

  public GitHubEmailVisibility getVisiblity() {
    return visiblity;
  }

  public void setVisiblity(GitHubEmailVisibility visiblity) {
    this.visiblity = visiblity;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    GitHubEmail that = (GitHubEmail) o;
    return primary == that.primary &&
        verified == that.verified &&
        Objects.equals(email, that.email) &&
        visiblity == that.visiblity;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {

    return Objects.hash(email, primary, verified, visiblity);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "GitHubEmail{" +
        "email='" + email + '\'' +
        ", primary=" + primary +
        ", verified=" + verified +
        ", visiblity=" + visiblity +
        '}';
  }
}
```

And this is the `GitHubEmailVisibility.java`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonValue;

/**
 * GitHub email visibility options.
 */
public enum GitHubEmailVisibility {

  PRIVATE,

  PUBLIC;

  @JsonValue
  public String toJson() {
    return name().toLowerCase();
  }

  @JsonCreator
  public static GitHubEmailVisibility fromValue(String value) {
    System.out.println("Is this ever even called?");
    if ("private".equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
      return PRIVATE;
    } else if ("public".equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
      return PUBLIC;
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Using Spring's RestTemplate, I make the call:

```
GitHubEmail[] gitHubEmails = rest.getForObject("https://api.github.com/user/emails?access_token={oAuthToken}&type=all&per_page=1000&page=1",
        GitHubEmail[].class, oAuthToken);
    Arrays.stream(gitHubEmails).forEach(gitHubEmail -> logger.info("GitHub email: " + gitHubEmail));
```

However, the `visibility` always comes back as `null` even though the payload string clearly has values for at least one of the emails in the array that comes back.

Also, I see that my `System.out.print` statement in the method with `@JsonCreator` never gets called.

Here is the output of the following lines together (first one, serializing the response as simple string, just to verify that `visibility` does get returned sometimes):

```
String emails = rest.getForObject("https://api.github.com/user/emails?access_token={oAuthToken}&type=all&per_page=1000&page=1",
        String.class, oAuthToken);
logger.info("emails consumed as a string: " + emails);

GitHubEmail[] gitHubEmails = rest.getForObject("https://api.github.com/user/emails?access_token={oAuthToken}&type=all&per_page=1000&page=1",
        GitHubEmail[].class, oAuthToken);
Arrays.stream(gitHubEmails).forEach(gitHubEmail -> logger.info("GitHub email: " + gitHubEmail));
```

Here is the server logs for those 2 sets of statements. As you can see, the string version has the first of 3 emails listed with `visibility: private`. However, *all* 3 emails deserialized into Java objects have `visibility` as `null`:

```
2018-05-01 21:42:51.477  INFO 5828 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] j.p.w.controller.LoginSuccessController  : emails consumed as a string: [{"email":"...","primary":true,"verified":true,"visibility":"private"},{"email":"...","primary":false,"verified":true,"visibility":null},{"email":"...","primary":false,"verified":true,"visibility":null}]
2018-05-01 21:42:51.524  INFO 5828 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] j.p.w.controller.LoginSuccessController  : GitHub email: GitHubEmail{email='...', primary=true, verified=true, visiblity=null}
2018-05-01 21:42:51.524  INFO 5828 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] j.p.w.controller.LoginSuccessController  : GitHub email: GitHubEmail{email='...', primary=false, verified=true, visiblity=null}
2018-05-01 21:42:51.524  INFO 5828 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] j.p.w.controller.LoginSuccessController  : GitHub email: GitHubEmail{email='...', primary=false, verified=true, visiblity=null}
```

How do I get it to get deserialized into this Java POJO model?

I am using Spring Boot 2.0 and it looks like it depends on Jackson 2.9.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hosted a sample json at https://api.myjson.com/bins/1h6ngn

And used the same classes, it runs fine.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {

    RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    GitHubEmail[] gitHubEmails = rest.getForObject("https://api.myjson.com/bins/1h6ngn", GitHubEmail[].class);
    Arrays.stream(gitHubEmails)
        .forEach(gitHubEmail -> System.out.println(("GitHub email: " + gitHubEmail)));
}
```

**Output**

```
Is this ever even called?
Is this ever even called?
GitHub email: GitHubEmail{email='hemantsonu20@gmail.com', primary=false, verified=true, visiblity=PRIVATE}
GitHub email: GitHubEmail{email='another@gmail.com', primary=true, verified=false, visiblity=PUBLIC}
```

Just change your rest call

```
String gitHubEmails = rest.getForObject("https://api.github.com/user/emails?access_token={oAuthToken}&type=all&per_page=1000&page=1",
        String.class, oAuthToken);
System.out.println(gitHubEmails);
```

Verify whether you are getting **"visiblity"** node in the json or not.

Comment: There is high chance that you are not getting **"visiblity"** node in github api response or you might be getting with other node name. Remove @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) from the bean to verify

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Hmm... Strange... I actually have that exact rest call right before the call with the custom object. That's how I *know* that visibility is most certainly coming back as `private` in the case I am testing. Not really sure why it's not even getting to that code then.

Comment: Another piece of info is that looking at the `String`-based REST call, I see that the array contains 3 items and 2 of them have `visibility` as `null`. Could that trip this whole thing up and it gives up or something?

Comment: There might be some other value for visibility other than public / private. Just log any unknown value before returning null in the `GitHubEmailVisibility#fromValue` method

Comment: I tested with my github token, and github api is itself returning null. https://pastebin.com/nyJ09r1r  . No issue at your code.

Comment: I just updated my question with the logs I am seeing. The `visibility`, at least in one of my cases, is not `null`, it's `private`. Yet, the POJOs show it as `null`.

Comment: Also, my logs do NOT show that the `fromValue` method is ever getting called, which is very weird, but would explain why I am getting `null` for that field.

Comment: OMG!!! I just saw the problem... LOL... The GitHubEmail property in my class is misspelled. It shows `visiblity` instead of `visibility`. Yikes! That was one hard thing to notice!!! Thanks for your help though!

Comment: As per my first comment, you could solve it earlier by removing @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true). So that serialization throws error when any unknown property is there